# Query to List all hierarchical parents and siblings and their childrens, but not list own childrens

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a basic SQL table with a simple heirarchial connection between each rows. That is there is a ParentID for Every rows and using that its connecting with another row. Its as follows

```
AccountID  |  AccountName  |  ParentID
---------------------------------------
    1            Mathew        0
    2            Philip        1
    3            John          2
    4            Susan         2
    5            Anita         1
    6            Aimy          1
    7            Elsa          3
    8            Anna          7
    .............................
.................................
    45           Kristoff      8
```

**Hope the structure is clear**

But my requirement of listng these is a little weird. That is when we pass an AccountID, it should list all its parents and siblings and siblings childrens. But it never list any child of that AccountID to any level. I can explain that in little more detail with a picture. Sorry for the clarity of the picture.. mine is an old phone cam..
[image]

**When we pass the AccountID 4**, it should list all Parents and its siblings, **but it should not list 4,6,7,8,9,10**. That means that account and any of it childrens should be avoid in the result (Based on the picture tree elements). Hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: Should it show also 5,11,12,... - whole table without  4,6,7,8,9,10? Or only parents of 4 - 2,1 ?

Comment: @valex Yes.. exactly.. thats I mentioned as its siblings and their childrens along with all its parents..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I've got it right and you need to output whole table except 4 and all of it's descendants then try this recursive query:

```
WITH CT AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM T WHERE AccountID=4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T.* FROM T 
     JOIN CT ON T.ParentID = CT.AccountId
)
SELECT * FROM T WHERE AccountID 
                NOT IN (SELECT AccountID FROM CT)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9230/2)</kbd>

Answering to the question in the comment:

> So it will not traverse to the top. It only traverse to specified
>   account. For example if I pass 4 as first parameter and 2 as second
>   parameter, the result should be these values 2,5,11,12

You should start from the ID=2 and travel to the bottom exclude ID=4 so you cut whole subtree after ID=4:

```
WITH CT AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM T WHERE AccountID=2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T.* FROM T 
     JOIN CT ON T.ParentID = CT.AccountId
  WHERE T.AccountId<>4
)

SELECT * FROM CT
```

Comment: Sorry.. I need little more support if you dont mind. How can we modify the query so that it will not go upwards from a second parameter. So it will not traverse to the top. It only traverse to specified account. For example if I pass 4 as first parameter and 2 as second parameter, the result should be these values 2,5,11,12

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select accountid,parentid, 0 as level from tbl
 where parentid = 0
 union all
 select t.accountid,t.parentid,(level+1) from 
 cte c inner join tbl t on c.accountid= t.parentid
)
select * from cte
where level < (select level from cte where accountid = @accountid)
```

When you pass in the parameter `@accountid` this will return the `accountid` values of all nodes on levels before that of the parameter.

If you want to return everything on the same level as input except input itself, you can change the `where` clause to;

```
where level <=(select level from cte where accountid= @accountid ) 
and accountid <> @accountid
```

In your example, if `@accountid` = 4, this will return the values 1,2,3 (ancestors) as well as 5,13,14 (siblings).

Answer (score 1):

Does this return what you are after?

```
declare @AccountID int
set @AccountID = 4

;with parents
as (

    select AccountID, AccountName, ParentID
    from Account
    where AccountID = (select ParentID from Account Where AccountID = @AccountID)

    union all

    select A.AccountID, A.AccountName, A.ParentID
    from Account as A
    join parents as P
        on P.ParentID = A.AccountID
    ),
children
as (
    select AccountID, AccountName, ParentID
    from parents

    union all

    select A.AccountID, A.AccountName, A.ParentID
    from Account as A
    join children as C
        on C.AccountID = A.ParentID
    where A.AccountID <> @AccountID
    )
select distinct AccountID, AccountName, ParentID
from children
order by AccountID
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it sounds like you want to go up in the tree. So considering this test data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(AccountID INT,AccountName VARCHAR(100),ParentID INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1,'Mathew',0),
(2,'Philip',1),
(3,'John',2),
(4,'Susan',2),
(5,'Anita',1),
(6,'Aimy',1),
(7,'Elsa',3),
(8,'Anna',7)
```

The I would write a query like this:

```
DECLARE @AcountID INT=4

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        tbl.AccountID,
        tbl.AccountName,
        tbl.ParentID
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.AccountID=@AcountID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tbl.AccountID,
        tbl.AccountName,
        tbl.ParentID
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
    JOIN CTE
        ON CTE.ParentID=tbl.AccountID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    NOT CTE.AccountID=@AcountID
```

This will return a result like this:

```
2   Philip  1
1   Mathew  0
```